# AJAX call in external JavaScript file not reaching ActionResult in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check if an email address exists in the database. I have an external JavaScript file that I am using to call my jQuery (to keep my view clean). Perhaps it is because I am running with SSL enabled? (I am using https)

Function in external js file:

```
function checkemail() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/CheckEmailExists/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ p: email }),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Action in Controller:

```
public ActionResult CheckEmailExists(string p)
            {
                bool bEmailExists = false;

                using (RBotEntities EF = new RBotEntities())
                {
                    var query = (from U in EF.AspNetUsers
                                 where U.Email == p
                                 select U).FirstOrDefault();

                    if(query.Email != null)
                    {
                        bEmailExists = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bEmailExists = false;
                    }
                }

                return Json(bEmailExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

I seem to be getting an error stating the following:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
>   https://localhost:44347/Account/CheckEmailExists/ Line Number 1,
>   Column 1:

My understanding would be that this `ActionResult` does not exist. But it does ?

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a reason why an `ActionResult` can not be called via an external JavaScript file ?

Comment: Your controller is receiving the request, but is reading it as XML. Which version of ASP.NET do you use? MVC2 doesn't have built-in json support while MVC3 does.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

In Controller

```
[httppost]
 public ActionResult CheckEma.........
```

In JS

```
function checkemail() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/CheckEmailExists/",
        data: { p: email },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The controller is still not being reached, and data is still returning what seems to be nothing or an empty string

Comment: Added [HttpPost] in my controller, but result is still the same :( I have this feeling there is some other underlying issue that is causing this. Ive done ajax calls in the past and all worked fine. Ive tried what you have suggested yesterday as well, but nothing is working... The error im getting is same as in my post : XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://localhost:44347/Account/CheckEmailExists/

Answer (score 1):

No need for `Json.Stringify` and `ContentType` here

```
function checkemail() {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/CheckEmailExists",
            data: { p: email },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The controller is still not being reached, and data is still returning what seems to be nothing or an empty string

Comment: remove the '/' after CheckEmailExist in Ajax Url

Comment: Why aren't you using Remote Validation to check the email Exist or not?

Comment: Removing the "/" unfortunately made no difference. Im doing a type of wizard that only submits at the end, so I am doing all my validation each time I move to the next step by using jqueries, so this is why I require to call an actionresult via ajax call. It makes no sense why this isnt working though.... It should be

Comment: try adding `dataType:"json"` in ajax call .Not sure if this will work or not

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Add `[HttpPost]` before your ActionMethod

Comment: Also tried that and not working. I might need to find an alternative solution....

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was causing the issue...

Above my Action result, I needed to add `[AllowAnonymous]` data annotation and then it reached my `ActionResult`! I would prefer to not allow anonymous, but it works and I wanted to share this in case it helps someone else. Below is my code:

ActionResult:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CheckEmailExists(string p)
{
    bool bEmailExists = false;

    using (RBotEntities EF = new RBotEntities())
    {
        var query = (from U in EF.AspNetUsers
                     where U.Email == p
                     select U).FirstOrDefault();

        if (query.Email != null)
        {
            bEmailExists = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bEmailExists = false;
        }
    }

    return Json(bEmailExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JavaScript function in JavaScript File:

```
function checkemail() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var bReturnedValue = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/CheckEmailExists/",
        data: { p: email },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data)
            {
                bReturnedValue = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bReturnedValue = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return bReturnedValue;
}
```

And this is how I initiated it(I am doing a popover to specify that the email exists):

```
$("#createacc_next").click(function () {
var bEmailExists = false;

 bEmailExists = checkemail();

if (bEmailExists) {
            $("#email").attr("disabled", false).css("border-color", "red");
            $('#email').popover({ title: 'Attention', content: 'Email address already exists', placement: 'top', trigger: 'focus' });
            Email_Validation_Passed = false;
        }
})
```